# hardhat deploy method not working anymore with fund how to fund the contract?

Tags: smartcontracts, web3js, hardhat, etherscan

So I have written the same code as the hardhat documentation suggest here for deploying with funding maybe.

```js
import hre from "hardhat";

const main = async () => {
  const currentTimestampInSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
  const ONE_YEAR_IN_SECS = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
  const unlockTime = currentTimestampInSeconds + ONE_YEAR_IN_SECS;
  const lockedAmount = hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("1");

  const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("WavePortal");
  const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy(unlockTime,
    { value: lockedAmount }
  );
  await waveContract.deployed();
  console.log("Contract deployed to:", waveContract.address);
}
```

but the problem is it will give me an error about the argument.
[image]

even if it's the same code that the documentation suggest here: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/deploying.

First I have written code in a different manner from `buildspace` website as a part of learning about web3.

```js
// from buildspace website
const main = async () => {
  const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("WavePortal");
  const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy({
    value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001"),
  });

  await waveContract.deployed();

  console.log("WavePortal address: ", waveContract.address);
};
```

This above code from `buildspace` but the problem is it will also give the error and I thought it could be the old deprecated code so I look into docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS `deploy()` function accepts N required params, followed by 1 optional:

- N arguments of the Solidity constructor
- 1 optional object that *overrides* default params of the deploying transaction (in your case the `value`)

Based on the error message "Expected 0-1 arguments", the `WavePortal` constructor expects 0 params. Which makes the `deploy()` function to expect 0 constructor params, plus the 1 optional overriding object.

However your code is trying to pass `unlockTime` as the constructor param.

Solution: Remove the `unlockTime` from the JS code - or accept it in the Solidity code.

Comment: I have to make the contract's constructor `payable` which was not specified in `hardhat docs` unfortunately because they were talking in the context of `Lock.sol` contract. Thanks for your answer, I understood deploy method actually depends upon the solidity contract.